# Kafka broker acknowledgement to java API producer and console-producer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have configured 3 nodes kafka(version 2.0.0) and 3 nodes zookeeper cluster. And Created one topic with replication factor 3, partitions 1 and broker level min-in-sync-replicas=2.

Case 1: When I down 2 kafka nodes then my java producer can able to send data even I configured the property '**acks=all**'. i.e., not giving `NotEnoughReplicas` error.

Case 2: When I down 2 kafka nodes then my console producer can't able to send data when I configured the property '**request.required.acks all**'. i.e., giving `NotEnoughReplicas` error.

what are the configurations should pass to java producer in case of kafka 2.0.0?

Comment: The console producer is just a wrapper around the Java producer. Not sure I understand the question

Comment: Could you show us your configuration class? Also, when your producer client connects on startup, what does the config output display for kafka?

Comment: I think it's because send is async. If you write a java producer with a callback for send, then you'll be able to catch the failure. See the accepted answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52649077/assert-kafka-send-worked/52659173#52659173

Comment: Thank you so much. I have done with callback, now it's working.