# Kafka - Retries in Kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka

In Kafka cluster , If retries is getting increased what would be cause of it ? 
What are the factors related to retries ?

Comment: Check out this link. Might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52649077/assert-kafka-send-worked/52659173#52659173

Answer (score 0):

On the Kafka producer side (the Java producer client) there are two types of possible errors: retriable and not retriable.
The retriable ones are errors that can be resolved just resending the message (so trying one more time), for example a connection error or a no-leader because a leader election could be run and a leader will be elected soon. In this case the producer tries to re-send the message until the send succeeded or the max number of configured retries are reached.
Other errors like when a message is too large are not retriable; they cannot be "fixed" just re-sending the message.